# A clean way to update attributes across objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to do something like this:

**Given:**

```
@user1
@user2
```

Where the Post model has (id, user_id)

```
@posts = @user1.posts
```

I want to take all of the posts of user1, and set the user_id to @user2

Is there an easy one liner way to do this? Or do I have to loop through all the @posts and update attributes and save the record?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the class method [`update_all`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all) on your Post class to accomplish this.  The first string passed is essentially the SET clause of an SQL update statement, the second string is the WHERE clause.

```
Post.update_all("user_id = #{@user2.id}", "user_id = #{@user1.id}")
```

Comment: +1 I like your answer too, but I try to say away from writing straight sql.

Answer (score 2):

I use the `_ids` attribute for this.

```
@user2.update_attribute(:post_ids, @user1.post_ids)
```

#### More explanation

If you type

```
@user1.post_ids # --> [1,2,3,4]
```

You will get all the ids for all the posts the user is connected to in an array.

You can also set the relationship in this way too

```
@user2.post_ids = [1,2] 
@user2.save
```

So, to solve what you are asking about I simply assigned the array of post ids of @user1 to the post ids for @user2.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not following?

Comment: There was a typo in my answer that is confusing.  I like KenB's answer too.

Comment: +1 I like your answer for it's pure rubyesque nature, and I didn't know that you could run update_attribute on virtual attrs like _ids.  Nice!  But the Post.update_all approach is significantly more efficient at the database, generating just a single update statement.

Comment: @KenB - I agree that it is better on the database side.